# Can increasing the capacity of a HashSet create Collisions?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashset

I am attempting to implement a simple HashSet using a C++ vector as the underlying data structure. To keep things simple, I will double the size of the vector and re-hash all existing elements whenever the user inserts a new element that causes a collision (i.e. when another element already exists at the index at which I am trying to add the new element). This is done via my function `increaseCapacityAndRehash()`.

My question is: **Is it possible that the act of simply doubling the number of buckets (a.k.a. the size of the vector) will introduce a collision amongst elements that already exist in the HashSet (assuming that there were no collisions prior to the capacity increase)?** If so, I suppose that I will need to test for collisions each time I double the number of buckets and then keep doubling them until there are no more collisions. But I would prefer to simplify the code as much as possible.

A proof would be very much appreciated!

For reference, here is my code to add an element to my HashSet:

```cpp
// Buckets that elements will be hashed into
struct Bucket
{
   Bucket() : value(0), isFilled(false) { }
   Bucket(int val) : value(val), isFilled(true) { }
   
   int value;
   bool isFilled;
};

// Underlying data structure for the hashset
std::vector<Bucket> buckets;

// Get the index at which a given element should be stored
std::size_t hash(int x)
{
   return std::abs(x) % buckets.size();
}

// Function to add elements to hash set
void add(int x)
{
   // Hash the element to determine which bucket to search
   std::size_t key = hash(x);
   
   // If the bucket is filled with some element other than x, then the new element creates collision
   if (buckets[key].isFilled && buckets[key].value != x)
   {
      // Double the capacity of the hash set until the collision goes away
      bool collisionExists = true;
      while (collisionExists)
      {
         increaseCapacityAndRehash();
         key = hash(x);
         if (!buckets[key].isFilled)
         {
            collisionExists = false;
         }
      }
   }
   
   // Add the new element to the hash set
   buckets[key].value = x;
   buckets[key].isFilled = true;
}

// Function to double the size of the vector and rehash all elements
void increaseCapacityAndRehash()
{
   // Save all elements currently in the hash set
   std::vector<int> save(size(), 0);
   for (std::size_t i = 0, save_i; i < buckets.size(); ++i)
   {
      // If element is a valid entry in the hash set, save it off
      if (buckets[i].isFilled)
      {
         save[save_i++] = buckets[i].value;
      }
   }
   
   // Double the number of buckets
   const std::size_t newCapacity = buckets.size() * 2;
   buckets = std::vector<Bucket>(newCapacity, Bucket());
   
   // Re-hash all elements
   for (int x : save)
   {
      const std::size_t key = hash(x);
      assert(buckets[key].isFilled == false);  // Can increasing number of buckets cause collisions???
      buckets[key].value = x;
      buckets[key].isFilled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the new element doesn't still collide with the same element as before. Otherwise, do you maintain a power-of-two bucket count?

Comment: @Caleth At some point, the capacity of the hashset should grow big enough that the new element and the element with which it collides can have `hash(x) == x`, correct? Although I guess this doesn't apply to negative numbers. Regarding the power-of-two bucket count, yes. I double the number of buckets based on `const std::size_t newCapacity = buckets.size() * 2;`

Comment: I've just looked at your (lack of) hash function. Yes, but you run the risk of running out of memory first. Do you *start* with a power-of-two bucket count?

Comment: Lol this implementation is meant to be as simple as possible. I start with 1 element in the vector so yes, it does start with a power of 2.

Comment: You *don't* have a hashset. You have a (vastly inferior) [dynamic_bitset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Comment: Regardless of the efficiency of this approach, can increasing the number of buckets potentially introduce collisions that did not exist before?

Comment: You have another problem.  If you have two entries, `x` and `-x`, they will _always_ collide, no matter how many times you double your number of buckets.

Comment: There is a lot of noise in this question. Could you reduce the information to just what is needed for your question? How general an answer do you want? For this particular example, it looks like the question comes down to: **for given non-negative integers `x` and `y` and positive `N`, if `x%N != y%n`, then is it guaranteed that `x%(2N) != y%(2N)`?** *Hmm... I guess you would need to mention that this came from a HashSet implementation, otherwise it might be dismissed as a purely mathematical question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double the number of buckets, you won't get any new collisions but you might not resolve your current collision.

The original hash value is computed as

```
hash = x % N;
```

where `x` is is some value, and `N` the number of buckets.  When you double the number of buckets, this becomes

```
new_hash = x % (2*N);
```

`new_hash` will either be `hash`, or `hash + N`. Since there is only one value that has the hash value `hash`, and all other values have hash values that are less than `N`, the new value not collide with any other new value (except possibly for the previously mentioned new element).

Another way to look at is the relation between the two hash values:

```
hash == new_hash % N
```

So if any of the new hash values collide, they will be colliding with the original hash values.

---

In general, however, hash sets will tolerate some amount of collisions because collisions are unavoidable. Growth is not merely a doubling of the number of buckets, and the new hash values can collide where they didn't originally do so.